# Prompt to download Flash from WebView goes to broken link

Tags: android

I have a video website that is Android compatible. Flash is required to view videos on my site. When Flash is not installed, I display an anchor linking to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ for the user to download Flash.

```
<a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">
   Flash player is required to watch this video
</a>
```

When viewing my website through the default Browser app, this anchor correctly opens up the Flash download page in the Market app. However, when my site is loaded through a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and the user taps the anchor, they are sent to a 404 page:

> Web page not available. 
>   The Web page at
>   market://details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer
>   might be temporarily down or it may
>   have moved permanently to a new web
>   address.

How would I make my website work for both the Browser app and any native app that loads my website through a WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent
you will need to use an intent to open the market URL. Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);    


    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {    
        if(url.contains("market://"))   
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Note: I did not test this, but you should get the general idea. if it is a market url then open the market app using an intent instead of trying to load the url.

Comment: This works. But here's the other problem: after installing Flash, the WebView doesn't realize that Flash is installed until the app is killed and restarted.

Comment: Right, not much you can do about that, need the flash plugin to get loaded in. Might want to try bringing up a toast popup when the adobe pages loads to let users know they need to restart. You could also setup for a new package install broadcast receiver and check to see if the adobe plugin is installed, then restart your app, but that is a bit more work for something simple. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html